# Jquery sliding a div out of the side of the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $('#right_image1').hide().delay('10000').fadeIn('5000');
      $('#left_image1').hide().delay('10000').fadeIn('5000');
    });
</script>

/* CSS */
#left_image1 { position: fixed; width: 50%; height: 100%; margin-left: 0; background: url(/images/1.jpg) } 
#right_image1 { position: fixed; width: 50%; height: 100%; margin-left: 50%; background: url(/images/2.jpg) }
```

This currently fades in two divs after a 10 second delay. How can I get the div on the right to slide out of the right side of the browser window after 5s of being displayed and the left div to slide out of the left side of the browser after 5s?

Comment: Can you show some css related to these divs ? The sliding will vary depending on the css you're using.

Comment: `#left_image1 { position: fixed; width: 50%; height: 100%; margin-left: 0; background: url(/images/1.jpg) }
#right_image1 { position: fixed; width: 50%; height: 100%; margin-left: 50%; background: url(/images/2.jpg) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cxxtq/).  Here is the updated JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#right_image1').delay(10000).fadeIn(500).delay(5000).animate({
        marginLeft: '100%'
    });
    $('#left_image1').delay(10000).fadeIn(500).delay(5000).animate({
        marginLeft: '-50%'
    });
});
```

Note that we use numbers for `delay` and the duration of `fadeIn`.  Then, we use `animate` to handle the left/right movement.

Additionally, we hide with CSS instead of JavaScript; that's best practice.

Also, we specify in the CSS the `left` value to avoid interaction from margin or padding on the `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$('#right_image1').hide().delay('10000').fadeIn('5000', function() {

    $(this).animate({right: '-1px'}, 5000);
});

$('#left_image1').hide().delay('10000').fadeIn('5000', function() {

    $(this).animate({left: '-1px'}, 5000);
});
```