# Create animated div which slides in and out from the side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I´m currently trying to create a bare clickdummy for an application layout. This layout contains some kind of details view on the right side, which shouldn´t be visible all the time but after you clicked on a button. I have no clue how to realize such a moving div using CSS or jQuery.

I´ve alredy tried to work with the CSS attribute `visibility` to show or hide the div, but it just pops up and doesn´t move in from the side.
Also I tried an approach with using `margin-left` on the details view but this destroyed my whole layout.

So what is the best way / best practice to realize such an moving div?

Here is my code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ew6xwfa/9/). The red `details` div is the one which should move.

```js
function toggleButton() {
 

}
```

```css
/*STYLE*/
.window {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: hidden;
}
.header, .footer {
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
}
.stage {  
  background-color: white;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.content{
  background-color: dimgrey; 
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 400px);
  float: left;
}

.details {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
}

#test-table {
  width: 100%;
}

#test-table td {
  text-align:center; 
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="window">  
        <div class="header">
          header
        </div>    
        <div class="stage">       
          <div class="navigation">
            navigation
          </div>      
          <div class="content">
            <table id="test-table" border=1>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Place</th>  
              <th>Details</th> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>John</td>
              <td>20</td>
              <td>USA</td>
              <td><input type="button" onclick="toggleButton()" value="i" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Mary</td>
              <td>30</td>
              <td>Canada</td>
              <td><input type="button" onclick="toggleButton()" value="i" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Tim</td>
              <td>40</td>
              <td>Germany</td>
              <td><input type="button" onclick="toggleButton()" value="i" /> </td>
            </tr>              
            </table>
          </div>      
          <div class="details" id="details">
            details
          </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
          footer
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT**

I found an interesting solution at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857092/jquery-sliding-a-div-out-of-the-side-of-the-browser-window?rq=1) question. I tried to use this approach ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ew6xwfa/11/)) but no my red div is to high. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want; I like to do with jQuery UI

```
$( "#button1" ).on('click', function() {
   $( "#details" ).toggle( "slow" , function() {
     // Animation complete.
   });
});
```

I also had to change some of your CSS from your fiddle, the `details` div should be `position:absolute;`

I also changed your input fields to `<input type="button" id="button1" value="i" />`
(instead of having the `onClick="toggleButton()"`, I gave the input an `id`).

If you want to learn more about the jQuery`.toggle()` effect; check [this](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) out.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ew6xwfa/12/)

it does move a little strange which confused me a bit. will work on that (unless you like it).

goodluck :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using css animation property. [Here is your updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cj8asonf/)

This is the code I used:

```
@keyframes move {
  0% { transform: translateX( 150px ) }
  50% { transform: translateX( 0 ) }
  100% { transform: translateX( 150px ) }
}
```

And then add to the `.details`

```
animation: move 1s ease;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

Comment: Oh, wait, you don't want it to move all the time. I'll update my fiddle briefly.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Is there a way how to trigger this animation with a button so I can decide whether my div is shown or not ?

Comment: The idea is to put the animation statements into another class and to toggle that class everytime you click the button. I don't have the time to change the code right now, sorry. Will change it later. But maybe you can already solve this on your own.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways that you can tackle this, as said by elementzero23, you can use keyframes which is mostly written in css.

You can also use JQUERY to edit the css or add/remove(toggle) class when there are multiple changes involved.

I prefer using JQUERY as it tends to be more simple, unless you have some pre-requisites.

Here's a sample
https://jsfiddle.net/ksf9jsbg/

HTML

```
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
.box1{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:20%;
  height:20%;
  background: #000;
}

.box2{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  width:20%;
  height:20%;
  background: #090;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;  /*ADD THIS TO ENSURE SMOOTH MOVEMENT*/
}
```

JS

```
$('.box1').mouseup(function() {
$('.box2').css("transform", "translateX(300px)"); //THE MOST IMPORTANT PART
});
```

Here, I only altered the transform property of a div with the class "box2".

EDIT

Here's an updated version of your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uy98mcL0/), try it.